# Installing OpenGL and compiling with command line on Windows

Tags: c++, opengl

So there is the problem: when I compile `#include <GL/gl.h>` or `#include <GL/glu.h>` error occurs: no such file or directory. I updated NVidia drivers but error stays.

I have been struggling in setting up OpenGL without GLUT. I have read countless tutorials, but all of them are for Microsoft Visual C++, which requires placing gl.h in this IDE internal include folder. And I am trying to using only command line to compile winapi applications.

What dlls should I download and where to place them?

Comment: Compiler usually has an option to pass a path where it should search for includes. If you are using gcc, the option is `-I`

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, OpenGL is provided as a static library, you do not need to get any DLLs (your graphics driver will provide OpenGL extensions). `GL.h` and `GLU.h` are included in the [Windows SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK), along with `OpenGL32.lib` and `GLU32.lib`. However, if you want to use anything other than OpenGL 1.1., you will need to get `wglext.h` and `glext.h` from [Khronos](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php). Your driver will provide the extension prototypes, which you get using [wglGetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386(v=vs.85).aspx) (this function is linked in with `OpenGL32.lib`).

Comment: If gl.h and glu.h are already provided, why "no such file or directory" error occurs then?

Comment: Because you're not giving the proper include directory. They are contained in the Windows SDK (in the "Include/um" subdirectory. Eg. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\gl\GL.h" for the Windows 8.1 SDK, installed in the default directory).